# using fork() to create process tree in C

Tags: c, bash, unix, process, tree

I have to create a process tree using fork() and if, else in C. The proc tree have to look like this:

[image]

My code in this moment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    fork();
    if(fork())
    {
        if(fork()){}
        else{fork();}
    }
pause();
return 0;
}
```

And i don't know what to do next. Can someone help me?

Comment: There is a similar answer here. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2353778/2717586

Maybe you can apply the answer to your situation.

Comment: You've asked this just earlier, or otherwise you had the same idea to make SO do the thinking for you as someone else in your class.

Comment: output tikz, thats what i did when we had to do this

Comment: why no one on this forum wants to help me? Probably it's not a difficult task as someone understands. Since yesterday i'm trying to do this. I miss only two processes in my tree. Is it a problem to help me and add something to the program? Your tips and links do not help me.

Answer (score 0):

The first should fork() 4 times, the first son should fork 2 times and its second son too; then the third son of the "root" should fork once.